# Path issue with Compass and Font-awesome

Tags: path, compass-sass, font-awesome

Here is my config.rb :

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
require 'font-awesome-sass'
require 'bootstrap-sass'

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"
```

And my styles.scss :

```
@import "bootstrap-variables";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome-compass";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "theme";
```

The issue is that my compiled css is :
css/styles.css
css/font-awesome/font-awesome.css

font-awesome.css font-face leads to : ../fonts

Which doesn't work, it should be either :

../../fonts

Or css/font-awesome.css instead of beeing in a sub-directory.

Any idea how to fix that?

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to also include the fonts_dir in your config.rb

fonts_dir       = "[path]/fonts"